# where is declared the constante Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-location

When I read the doc : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest then say that `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` is deprecated and that we must use instead `Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`. but when i do so i receive :

> error: cannot find symbol
> .setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also [`LocationRequest.setPriority()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setPriority(int)) has become deprecated and been replaced by [`LocationRequest.Builder.setPriority()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.Builder#setPriority(int)) where

> The default value is [`Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Priority#PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY).

So in your case you don't need to call `setPriority()` at all.

Further note, that `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` has been moved from **class** [`LocationRequest`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) to **interface** [`Priority`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Priority).